# Remove Highlight Effect from ListViewItem

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, styles, itemcontainerstyle

In a `ListView` there are `ListviewItems` where they must not change appearance when the mouse is over them or they are selected.

I tried to accomplish that with this style and did *somewhat* succeed:

```
<Style x:Key="ItemContainerStyle1" TargetType="ListViewItem">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
            <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

But the it raised a new issue. When the background is set to "Transparent" I am now able to see this hover/glossy effect that is shown at the picture below, when the mouse is over a list view item.

[image]

I have tried to solve the problem with this attempt, but with no luck.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
    <Style.Resources>
      <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="#00000000"/>
      <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="#00000000"/>
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```

Anyone have an idea how to remove this hover effect?

Comment: If anyone needs just list of controls (without a table), use `ItemsControl` https://stackoverflow.com/a/17853517/6131611

Answer (score 146, accepted):

I don't know if this is the only solution but I did it as follows (by setting the `Template` property of the `ListViewItem`s):

```xml
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                    <Border
                         BorderBrush="Transparent"
                         BorderThickness="0"
                         Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <GridViewRowPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" Width="Auto" Margin="0" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

---

EDIT:

Or as Grant Winney suggests (I did not test that myself):

```xml
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                    <ContentPresenter />
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Comment: Thanks, this solved my problem :) Been using two days on this!
I was wondering if you knew a good book or some good homepages to get knowledge about styling?

Comment: Only [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/), http://wpftutorial.net/ and Google, sorry.. maybe anybody else has an idea.

Comment: I tested @GrantWinney's solution, and it works well.

Comment: Total life saver @Matmarbon. I used Grant Winney's solution, also. In the end, I needed a ListView to contain items in the width of the window, where a Scrollviewer would not suit - I didn't need any of the hover/tap styling, so thank you very much +1 :)

Comment: Best answer! The second one is the best, the first one made my entire component disappear.

Comment: First solution works for ListView with GridView, second one works with ListView without GridView.

Comment: @Grant as per your suggestion. I implemented your solution in my ListView. My listview is having a custom item template. On applying your solution, Highlight effect gets disabled but it does not apply foreground and background properties applied on my ListViewItem. Can you please what should be added/removed in your solution while using custom ItemTemplate in ListView? Thanks.

Comment: @Matmarbon On applying your solution it disables the highlight effect of the selected item in list view, but it somehow makes the foreground of text inside ListViewItem transparent. The text inside the ListViewItem is not visible. How can I make it visible?

Comment: @GrantWinney 's Solution is what have been working for me.

Comment: @GrantWinney 's solution works great for me! It removes the MouseOver and Selected effects, which is exactly what I needed (it can be used to simulate line-by-line animation of text). The first one made the contents of my ListView disappear.

Answer (score 6):

For me, worked well, like this:

```
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
  <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
    <Style.Triggers>
      <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
      </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
  </Style>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Answer (score 6):

This work:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">  
<Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
<Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
<Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
            <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                <Border Name="Selection" Visibility="Collapsed" />
                <!-- This is used when GridView is put inside the ListView -->
                <GridViewRowPresenter Grid.RowSpan="2"
                                      Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                      HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                      VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                      SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>

            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

Comment: This is the only option that works when you are using a GridView.  Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Did not the question but this worked for me .

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                        <Border Name="Border" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" />
                            </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

Comment: This vesrion works in my case, having a nested listview.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, but none of the answers helped me. Searching on the web i found this solution and it worked:

```
        <ListView.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                            <GridViewRowPresenter />
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </ListView.Resources>
```

Answer (score 3):

This answer is similar to that by Big Kev but for a `GridView` which needs the `GridViewRowPresenter` instead of the `ContentPresenter`.

I liked Kev's answer best because it removed the default hover highlighting and still gives control over the style using the `IsMouseOver` Trigger which the other answers did not.

```
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
            <Border Name="Border" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
                                  BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" 
                                  Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                <GridViewRowPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                      Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" />
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one it worked for me.

```
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="2,3,2,3" />
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just added code this in ControlTemplate Trigger :

```
<Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
     <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
     <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource White_200}"/>
</Trigger>
```

Here is full Example for ListViewItem Template Style;

```
<ListView x:Name="ListViewMenu" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SubItems}" 
                      Background="Transparent" Foreground="White" BorderThickness="0"
                      ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                      ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                      Height="210">
                <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#808182" />
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                                    <Border x:Name="Bd" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                                    </Border>
                                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}"/>
                                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}}"/>
                                        </Trigger>
                                        <MultiTrigger>
                                            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                                <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="true"/>
                                                <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive" Value="false"/>
                                            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}}"/>
                                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightTextBrushKey}}"/>
                                        </MultiTrigger>
                                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                                        </Trigger>
                                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource White_200}"/>
                                        </Trigger>
                                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" Padding="20 5" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```