# Remove shadow from selected ListView Item

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, wpf-controls, listviewitem

I did some research on how to remove the default highlighting of a selected listview item. The problem is that while it does change the color, it does not remove the shadow. How do I remove the shadow?

```
             <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                    <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseDoubleClick" Handler="TrackList_DoubleClick" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#282828"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#282828" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#333333" />
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#333333" />
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
```

Here is what I'm talking about [image]

Notice that the item has this shadow across half of the item. Any help on fixing this would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16477552/wpf-remove-highlight-effect-from-listviewitem

Comment: @JonathanWilson nvm. I got it working. The answer in the question you linked works.

Comment: Great! Glad you got it :)

Comment: @JonathanWilson Thanks for the help :)