# Remove magnify effect from ListViewItem

Tags: wpf, xaml

I've followed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16477552/wpf-remove-highlight-effect-from-listviewitem) to get rid of the highlight effect in my ListView. The highlight effect is disabled correctly, but I'm still getting a magnify effect on the MouseOver. It's very anoying especially when moving over the ListView because it give a blury effect.

Here is my code

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Roles}" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
                    <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListView>
```

And this:

[image]

is the behavior I'm willing to get rid off.

Does anyone know how to get rid of this magnify effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rather than changing border thickness

```
<Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
```

hide it by changing border color

```
<Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{x:Null}" />
```