# How do I change the DataGrid cell hover colour in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, xaml

How would I go about changing the datagrid hover colour in wpf?

I want the hover colour to go from this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xPHB2.jpg

To my own custom colour.

Comment: Follow this link: (I can't comment yet)
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16491211/8649015

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define style for DataGridCell as following:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```