# how to remove color border and background when hover in listview wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net

when I mouse move in listview, It looks like the border and background color have changed as below image 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d9tj3.jpg)

I designed XAML as follows:

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="ResultViewer"
                      Background="Black"
                      Grid.Row="1"
                      ScrollChanged="ListResult_ScrollChanged"                     
                      VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                      VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                      MouseDoubleClick="BidingData_MouseDoubleClick">
            <ListView x:Name="ListResult"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ResultSearch.ListResult, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                      Height="Auto"
                      BorderBrush="Black"
                      Background="Black"
                      BorderThickness="0"
                      PreviewMouseMove="ListResult_PreviewMouseMove"
                      ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"
                      ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                      ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="True"
                      ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">                
                <ListView.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <ItemsPresenter />
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </ListView.Template>
                <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <MultiTrigger>
                                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Property="IsSelected"
                                     Value="True"/>
                                    <Condition Property="IsFocused" Value="True"></Condition>
                                    <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"/>
                                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <MultiTrigger.Setters>
                                    <Setter Property="Background"
                                        Value="Transparent" />
                                    <Setter Property="Foreground"
                                        Value="Transparent" />
                                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
                                        Value="Transparent" />
                                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness"
                                        Value="0" />
                                </MultiTrigger.Setters>
                            </MultiTrigger>

                        </Style.Triggers>
                        <Style.Resources>
                            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}"
                                             Color="Transparent" />
                            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}"
                                             Color="Transparent" />
                        </Style.Resources>
                    </Style>
```

I wish remove it into Transparent but do not working, I tried handle event PreviewMouseMove

```
Private Sub ListResult_PreviewMouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs)
        If ListResult IsNot Nothing Then
            ListResult.Focus()
            ListResult.Foreground = CType((New BrushConverter().ConvertFrom("#00FFFFFF")), SolidColorBrush)
            ListResult.Background = CType((New BrushConverter().ConvertFrom("#00FFFFFF")), SolidColorBrush)
            ListResult.BorderBrush = CType((New BrushConverter().ConvertFrom("#00FFFFFF")), SolidColorBrush)
        End If
    End Sub
```

but not working, So how should I do it thanks

Comment: This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16477552/remove-highlight-effect-from-listviewitem/16491211#16491211) could help.

Comment: @Insane thanks you, it's working, Now if I want to after loaded the data, is it ok to highlight?

Comment: As a note, setting `Mode=TwoWay` and `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` on the ItemsSource Binding is pointless. The Binding is inherently OneWay, and UpdateSourceTrigger only has an effect in TwoWay or OneWayToSource Bindings.

Comment: As another note, `CType((New BrushConverter().ConvertFrom("#00FFFFFF")), SolidColorBrush)` looks totally odd when you could simply use `Brushes.Transparent`.

Comment: it's VB.net code. Brushes.Transparent not working because value of type 'brush' cannot be converted to 'Brush'